# In Magit log buffer, is there key bindings for traversing in a branch?

Tags: magit

In a log buffer with multiple branches (using the <kbd>lL</kbd> command, with any <kbd>=o</kbd> option), a commit and its immediate parent or child may be shown far apart on the view and is difficult to trace back and forth among the commits in a branch. (All the current traverse keys will step onto every log line in the view).

Is there any way to confine my traverse to a selected branch or creating short-cut keys (such as <kbd>M-p</kbd>, <kbd>M-n</kbd>) to jump to immediate parent/child?

I know the <kbd>-D</kbd> and <kbd>-f</kbd> options but I often found that I need very detail history to correctly doing the merge or rebase operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there currently is no such key binding. (You may wish to open a feature request.)